# Are quoted AWS network speeds in each direction, or half in each direction?

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have an r3.8xl Redis Elasticache. We're seeing a maximum network output of 40 billion bytes in Cloudwatch Metrics. That equates to ~5GBit/sec out, but the quoted speed is 10GBit.

Is that expected?